# Rails: clean up messy controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I've got a long controller method with a lot of redirect conditions:

```
def show
  get_param_user
  if params[:id].match(/\D/)
    @document = Document.where(:user_id => @user.id, :issue => params[:id]).first
  else
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  end
  unless @document.blank?
    unless @document.template.name == "Media"
      unless @document.retired?
        @creator = User.find(@document.user)
        if @creator == @user # if document exists, based on name and id
          @document.components.each do |a|
            redirect_to share_error_url, :flash => { :error =>  "#{@document.title} contains retired content and is now unavailable." } if a.retired? and return
          end
          render @document.template.name.downcase.parameterize.underscore
        end
      else # if retired
        redirect_to share_error_url, :flash => { :error =>  "That document has expired." } and return
      end
    else # if media
      redirect_to share_error_url, :flash => { :error =>  "Media has no public link." } and return
    end
  else # if document doesn't exist
    redirect_to share_error_url, :flash => { :error =>  "Can't find that document. Maybe check your link. Or maybe it was deleted. Ask #{@user.name}." } and return
  end
end
```

As you might guess, it's prone to errors under certain conditions. Is there a neater way to rewrite it to make it more robust? I know methods should have only one `render` or `redirect_to` each, but I'm not sure how else to achieve what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know this as well, as a lot of my code currently looks like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few specific and little things.

First, in general, better don't use `until` with an `else` condition, and even less if you can use an `if`:

```
unless @document.blank?
```

is the same as

```
if @document.present?
```

Second, you use

```
    @creator = User.find(@document.user)
```

when usually you can simply use:

```
    @creator = @document.user
```

The semantics is a bit different (in the first case if `@document.user` is `nil` you'll immediatelly get an exception, in the secnond case not), but the second is what you commonly need.

Third, if it is sensible, you can move code to the model away from the controller, and use some nice enumerators:

```
def has_retired_components?
  @document.components.any?(&:retired?)
end
```

Also, your controller method is not *that* complex. It is just

```
if @document.present? and @document.showable? # also @document.try(:showable?)
  render whatever
else
  redirect_to error_url, flash: { error: error_message }
end
```

`error_message` may be the result of a method call (on the object itself if it makes sense). That way you move the logic to verify if the oject is showable somewhere else where it is less muddled with rendering logic.

The problem is that if you have a `showable?` method and another to show error messages, you have to be sure that the business logic is always correct in both. An option is to treat it similarly to how validations work: have a method (lets call it with the horrible name `showable_validation` here just to go on) that returns a hash with the errors and messages (the reasons for the object not being showable, like `{title: 'this is an error message'}`. The `showable?` method would then be:

```
def showable?
  showable_validation.empty?
end
```

and then you would also have in the model something like:

```
def showable_error
  showable_validation.values.first
end
```

And that would be the `error_message` (`@document.showable_error`). That way, the logic is only in one method.

Comment: Excellent answer, exactly the sort of things I was looking for. Thank-you.

Comment: If I was to use the `has_retired_components?` enumerator and the document fails that condition, would you happen to know how I can write an error into it for display in `error_message`?

Comment: Ah! I reread your answer and made sense of it. Thanks so much!